# When is a distribution having a finite support actually zero?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, schwartz-distributions

Let $D$ be a differential operator with smooth coefficients in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $E$ is a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose $u$ is a function that is smooth up to the boundary of $E$. If $D(u\cdot\chi_{E})$, as a distribution in $\mathbb{R}^n$, has a finite support, is it true that $D(u\cdot\chi_{E})$ is actually zero?

The answer is no in the case $n=1$. An example is $D=d/dx$, $E=(0,1)$ and $u(x)=1$ for all $x$. In this case, the support of $D(u\cdot\chi_{(0,1)})$ is $\{0,1\}$. I hope that the answer is yes if $n\geq 2$. If the answer is yes, what weaker conditions in u are actually needed to guarantee that the answer is yes? Any suggestion for appropriate references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the answer is no even in higher dimension, since the gradient of any characteristic function $\chi_\Omega$, $\Omega\Subset\Bbb R^n$ as exactly the same properties of $D=d/dx$, i.e. $\nabla \chi_\Omega\subseteq\partial\Omega$ as it is shown in [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2835353/domains-for-which-the-divergence-theorem-holds). And if you need a single PDE satisfying this property, you can take the divergence of the gradient and form the laplacian of the characteristic function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $E$ be the square $(0,1)^2$ in $R^2$, $D=\partial_x\partial_y$ and $u=1$. The support of $D(\chi_E u)$ is the set of corners of $E$.

Comment: Up to a factor  $1/\sqrt\pi $.

Comment: $E$ seems unbounded in you example.

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your answer and only keep the $\partial_x\partial_y$ example? the first part is wrong not only because the domain is unbounded, but more importantly because the fundamental solution is NOT smooth up to the boundary

Comment: Right. I just liked much more the fundamental solution example :)

Comment: While I will accept your answer for the original question, if $E$ is the unit ball (or generally, $E$ has a smooth boundary), would there be an example to show that the answer is also no? The unit ball is what I need but since I (falsely) hoped that the answer were yes, my original question asked for arbitrary $E$.

Comment: If $E$ has a smooth boundary, we can assume it is a half space $x_n>0$ near a point (say the origin) of the support of $D(\chi_Eu)$. Then $\chi_E=H(x_n)$ and we can write $D(\chi_Eu)=\Sigma_{j=0}^k a_j(x)H^{(j)}(x_n)$. Then $a_k$ must vanish in a punctured nbh of the origin in $x_n=0$ and so also at the origin by continuity (assuming n>1). Using that $x_nH^{(k)}(x_n)$ is a multiple of $H^{(k-1)}(x_n)$ we can eliminate the highest order term in the sum and inductively continue to eliminate all (I guess).

Comment: In the smooth case I believe you are right, and it might be sufficient to consider the case $E$ is a half space (EDIT: see the previous comment :)

Comment: What weaker conditions on u can we have  for the conclusion to hold still? Of course we only need derivatives of u up to the order of D but can we do less than that?

Comment: I think that kind of assumption is very close to necessary. If you consider again the heat kernel example, integrating once w.r.to time you get a bounded (Holder 1/2) counterexample for the operator $D=\partial_t(\partial_t-\partial_{xx})$